# Writing array of structs to binary file using fwrite

Tags: c, io, fwrite

I have:

```
pointfile = fopen("points.bin", "wb");
void    savepoints(point points[], int n, FILE f){
    fwrite(&points, sizeof(point), n, &f);
    return;
}
fclose(pointfile);
```

where `typedef struct {float x; float y;} point;`

and called by `savepoints(buffer, npoints, *pointfile);`

But nothing is written to the file. Can anyone spot my mistake? I can't see how to go about this, and other's I find searching either don't relate, or have merely got me this far.

Comment: should pass in a `FILE *` to `savepoints`

Comment: does it make a difference, since I had `...*pointfile` and `...&f`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fwrite(points` instead of `fwrite(&points`?

Comment: @OllieFord Pass FILE* as suggested. FILE can be copied, but because it contains things like the current stream position, you may run into unexpected issues if you copy it, write using that file, then use the original copy outside of savepoints.

Comment: actually it does matter since `&f != pointfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to pass a `FILE *` as parameter like:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
  float x,
        y;
}point;

/* function to save points data to myfile */
void save_points(point *points, int num_points, FILE *myfile)
{
  /* have to use points not (&points) here */
  fwrite(points, sizeof(point), num_points, myfile);
}

int main()
{
  FILE *pointfile;
  point *points; int num_points, index;
  pointfile = fopen("points.txt", "w");
  if(!pointfile)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create file 'points.txt'\n");
    goto err0;
  }
  num_points = 10;
  points = malloc(num_points * sizeof(point));
  if(!points)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to alloc `points`\n");
    goto err1;
  }
  /* points are uninitialized but can still write uninitialized memory to file to test.. */
  save_points(points, num_points, pointfile);
  free(points);
  fclose(pointfile);
  return 0;

err1:
  fclose(pointfile);
err0:
  return 0;
}
```

**Results**

```
$ ./test
$ ls -l points.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 80 Dec 14 22:24 points.txt
```